# PHP: values assigend to array are truncated to the first letter

Tags: php, fgetcsv

Strange behaviour in values assignement for an array.
The PHP script reads a csv file and fills an array variable with the values read from the file.

I put an echo command in the while cycle in order to see the first 8 lines read:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    // numero di elementi presenti nella riga letta
    $num_elementi = count($data); if($nn<8) echo "<br>-- nn:".$nn;
    // popolamento dell'array
    for ($x=0; $x<$num_elementi; $x++) {
        $csvarray[$nn][$x] = $data[$x]; if($nn<8) echo " - ".$csvarray[$nn][$x];
    }
    $nn++;
}
```

The result is truncated at the first characters:

```
> -- nn:0 - A - A - W - F - 1 - - 1 - 0 - - 0
> -- nn:1 - A - A - W - F - 1 - 5 - 7 - 6 - 3 - 5
> -- nn:2 - A - A - W - M - 3 - 4 - 3 - 1 - 2 - 1
> -- nn:3 - A - A - W - M - 3 - 6 - 3 - 7 - 4 - 7
> -- nn:4 - A - A - W - M - 1 - 3 - 1 - 7 - 2 - 7
> -- nn:5 - A - A - W - M - 2 - 1 - 2 - 6 - 1 - 6
> -- nn:6 - A - A - W - M - 3 - 3 - 3 - 8 - 1 - 8
> -- nn:7 - A - A - W - F - 2 - 6 - 2 - 1 - 3 - 1
```

If I print the $data variable (the difference with the previous code is the second echo command)

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    // numero di elementi presenti nella riga letta
    $num_elementi = count($data); if($nn<8) echo "<br>-- nn:".$nn;
    // popolamento dell'array
    for ($x=0; $x<$num_elementi; $x++) {
        $csvarray[$nn][$x] = $data[$x]; if($nn<8) echo " - ".$data[$x];
    }
    $nn++;
}
```

I get the correct result:

```
-- nn:0 - AFGHANISTAN - AFGHANISTAN - WIS GREY ROUTE - FIXED - 1 - - 1 - 0 - - 0
-- nn:1 - AFGHANISTAN - AFGHANISTAN - WIS SARL - FIXED - 104 - 55.2599833333333 - 78 - 61 - 3315.599 - 59
-- nn:2 - AFGHANISTAN - AFGHANISTAN AWCC MOBILE - WIS SARL - MOBILE - 36 - 48.57 - 32 - 10 - 2914.2 - 10
-- nn:3 - AFGHANISTAN - AFGHANISTAN ETISALAT MOBILE - WIS SARL - MOBILE - 36 - 6.7854 - 36 - 7 - 407.124 - 7
-- nn:4 - AFGHANISTAN - AFGHANISTAN MOBILE - WIS SARL - MOBILE - 16 - 37.5628333333333 - 14 - 7 - 2253.77 - 7
-- nn:5 - AFGHANISTAN - AFGHANISTAN MTN MOBILE - WIS SARL - MOBILE - 26 - 16.7021166666667 - 26 - 6 - 1002.127 - 6
-- nn:6 - AFGHANISTAN - AFGHANISTAN ROSHAN MOBILE - WIS SARL - MOBILE - 31 - 32.93085 - 30 - 8 - 1975.851 - 8
-- nn:7 - ALBANIA - ALBANIA - WHITE LABEL (WIS) - FIXED - 2495 - 6269.08833333333 - 2451 - 1416 - 376145.3 - 1413
```

It's just an assignment, why I get different results?

Put a var_dump of csvarray at the end of the loop:

```
echo "<br>VARDUMP = "; var_dump($csvarray[0]);
```

The result is:

```
VARDUMP=string(26) "AAWF1100omunicazioni SpA"
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($csvarray)` after the loop to see what's inside ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `$csvarray[$nn][$x]` and `$data[$x]` are the same thing. You just set `$data[$x]` equal to `$csvarray[$nn][$x]` in the previous statement.

Comment: I've made an edit with the result of var_dump

Answer (score 0):

At the line 6 you have to use the following code:

```
$csvarray[$nn][$x] = $data[$x]; if($nn<8) echo " - ".$csvarray[$nn];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved initializing the array with `$csvarray=Array(Array())` at the beginning of the code.
The array is used before, it's not empty when I use it again.